# Find and name a text box in a spreadsheet using VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, vba

Each sheet in my Excel Workbook has one basic text box. Unfortunately these are named differently each time (Text Box 1, Text Box 17, etc.).

I have a code that finds text box 1 and moves it. However, is there some way in VBA to say "find text box on active sheet and name text box 1". Or is there someway to just say "find any text box and do action?"

I'm unable to find the correct way to use the Shapes object/method.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim txBox As Shape

For Each ws In Worksheets
ws.Activate
    Set txBox = ws.Shapes("Text Box 1")
    txBox.IncrementLeft 200
Next ws
```

Comment: If you are sure that there is exactly one textbox on every sheet, use `ws.Shapes(1)` instead of `ws.Shapes("Text Box 1")`.

Answer (score 1):

This code will move all text boxes in the workbook to the right.

```
Sub blah()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim txBox As Shape

For Each ws In Worksheets
    For Each txBox In ws.Shapes
        If txBox.Type = msoTextBox Then txBox.IncrementLeft 200
    Next txBox
Next ws
End Sub
```

It iterates through the `Shapes` collection on each worksheet. It then checks if the shape is a text box and then moves it if it is. There's no need to rename the text boxes if you do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub SetTextBoxNames()
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In Worksheets

        If ws.Shapes.Count <> 0 Then
            If ws.Shapes(1).Type = msoTextBox Then   'or = 17
                ws.Shapes(1).Name = "TextBox1"
                ws.Shapes(1).IncrementLeft 200
            End If
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```